# AJP Connector or HTTP Connector

Tags: apache, tomcat7, connector, ajp, ibmhttpserver

We have a web application (3rd party product) hosted in Tomcat 6x server. We will be installing a IBM HTTP Server as Web Server in-front of the Tomcat server. While doing this, the product vendor has asked us to use HTTP connector (instead of AJP Connector) for communication between Tomcat & the IHS Web Server.

The few articles i read seems to be pointing that,

> an AJP connector will provide faster performance than proxied HTTP....  It is otherwise functionally equivalent to HTTP clustering.

1. Apart from performance, are there any other reasons when we should go for an AJP Connector and when we should go for an HTTP Connector ?

2. Are there any other side effects because of this choice of HTTP Connector, instead of AJP Connector ?

**Note**: Our application has approx 80 concurrent users during peak time.

Answer (score 0):

AJP permits the proxy to tell the backend about client SSL certificate details, which in Java EE are used to satisfy some HTTPServletRequest APIs.

You shouldn't use either in IHS, though, with an application server IHS wasn't bundled with. You'll have no support, and the generic proxy support is not really maintained actively.